# django-allauth test request as authenticated user

Tags: django, authentication, testing, django-allauth

I have a new Django project (version 2.2), a custom user model and `django-allauth` to manage user registration (not via social, just with the email confirmation) and I'm trying to test some protected views.

In the `setUp` method of the test I create a new user and create a new `EmailAddress` (from `allauth.account.models`) with `verified` and `primary` set to `True`.

Next I try to login with: `self.client.login(username=username, password=password)`
and I get `True` so everything is working so far and the user is logged.

If I try to view anything that requires login, I get a 301 redirect to the login page.

Here's my code:

**user creation in setUp**

```
username = 'test@test.com'
password = 'testtesttest'

new_user = User.objects.create_user(
    username=username,
    email=username,
    password=password,
    )
new_user.save()
new_user.is_active = True
new_user.save()

new_email_address = EmailAddress(
    user_id=new_user.id,
    email=username,
    verified=True,
    primary=True,
    )
new_email_address.save()
```

**login and test logged in**

```
logged_in = self.client.login(email=username, password=password)
self.assertTrue(logged_in)  # and this works as expected
```

Now if I try to request a view that requires login:

```
response = self.client.get("/protected")
```

I get `<HttpResponsePermanentRedirect status_code=301, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="/protected/">`

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: A redirect to the login page due to a user not being logged in (with the `login_required` decorator) would be a 302 redirect, not a permanent redirect 301. You're seeing the redirect to "/protected/" (with slash), not to the login page, you can see that because it actually says `url="/protected/"`. You should add `follow=True` to your `get()` call that way you can test the final response contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The redirect you're showing actually shows you the url it's redirecting to: `url="/protected/"`. So you're not redirected to the login page.

Note that a normal redirect would be 302 redirect (temporary), whereas here you see a permanent redirect, 301.

Either request the correct url (`self.client.get('/protected/')`) or follow through the redirects: `self.client.get('/protected', follow=True)`. That way your response will be for the final page and you can test whether its contents are what you expect.

Comment: So it was just the missing trailing slash at the and of the get request! It's working now, thank you so much!